# RewriteRule - Вопрос по .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

К домену привязан алиас alias-example.com

Имеется правило

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alias-example.com$ 
RewriteRule test /temp_1/YS/
```

При переходе по alias-example.com/test открывать содержимое /temp_1/YS/ Переход выполняется, открывается index.html но вот подключенные скрипты, стили путь которых относительный не загружаются. С помощью консоли выяснил что он ищет их в alias-example.com/ т.е. в корне. Как мне заставить его искать в нужной директории?

Comment: __DIR__  - папка где лежит скрипт, стройте пути от нее

Comment: @splash58 не совсем понял ваш ответ. 
upd. вы не это имели ввиду?  
<?php
 echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.__DIR__.'\style.css">';
?>